# How does Data Binding work with DataBindingUtil.bind vs ActivityBinding.inflate in Android

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-databinding

I am learning MVVM and I am confused with binding activity and its view.

in Data Binding course, it says, I need to

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view) // binding is in the field.
```

But MVVM course, it says, I need to

```
MainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).also{
    binding = it // binding is in the field
    setContentView(it.root)
}
```

I am using the second one and daat binding expression in XML doesn't work.
I don't know if it's a good access but, I am trying to get the data from ViewModel class.

So, What I did is,

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.my_app.ui.main.MainViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:text="@{viewModel.user.name}"
    />
    <TextView
        android:text="@{viewModel.getUserHeight()}
    />
</layout>
```

The ViewModel is

```
class MainViewModel(
        a: UserData,
): ViewModel() {
    private val _userData = MutableLiveData<UserData>()
    val userData: LiveData<UserData>
        get() = _userData

    init {
        _userData.value = a
        Log.i("view-model", "${_userData.value?.name}")
    }

    fun getUserHeight():String{
        return "${a.value.height}cm"
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.i("view-model", "MainViewModel destroyed")
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. Could you please explain which part is incorrect?

Comment: Make sure to provide viewModel reference to binding `binding.setViewModel(viewModel)`

Comment: well, I do `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)`. does it have any problems? @JaiprakashSoni

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, you should do something like this  :

```
val mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
// I dont know how you provide viewModel in your project, it doesn't matter in this case.
fun onCreate(bundle : Bundle){
  val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
  binding.viewModel = mainViewModel
}
```